# Let one object mimic the rotation of another animated object

Tags: blender

I want one object to mimic another one belonging the rotation.

My explicit example:
I rotate the camera via Animation.
A cube in the scene should represent this rotation, by mimicking it.

Comment: maybe better suited on https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [constraints](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/animation/constraints/introduction.html) to easily link various motions between multiple objects. The [Copy Rotation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/animation/constraints/transform/copy_rotation.html#) constraint should do what you want.

The constraints provide a simple GUI to some presets for the underlying [drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/animation/drivers/introduction.html) system. If the constraints aren't enough, you can use python to control values in almost any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to directly match another object's rotation, but I've always done this by just grouping objects together, or by making them the child of an empty.

So in your case, a quick and rough way is to set the camera to be the parent of the cube (Ctrl+P) and the cube should now match its rotation.

Note that you might want to move the origin of the camera to change the rotation axis.